# Extract Multiple values from single line and put them in same group in Regex

Tags: regex, logging, extract

Trying to extract multiple values from single sentence and put them in single group.

Sample sentences:

```
Abstracts:12345,56789,12321,35435,....n    (where n=100 max means limit is 100 value per sentence)
Abstract:12357                             (here only 1 value)
```

I used the following regex to capture both,

```
Abstrac\w+\:(\S+)
```

Its capturing all the values and putting it under 2 groups called Abstracts & Abstract

```
Abstracts                      Abstract
12345,56789,12321,35435        12357
```

I need single values without commas one below the other(i.e extract multiple values separately and put in group) and that too in one group, i am scratching my head over this, could anyone help on this?

Result that i need,

```
Abstract
12345
56789       
12321
35435
12357
... and so on
```

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!\A),|Abstrac\w+:)([^\s,]+)` if you use PCRE, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZwByiN/1). `(?:\G(?!\A),|Abstrac\w+:)\K[^\s,]+` might work then, too, but it depends on the actual code that is behind this.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, actually the sentences are logs and i am trying to extract the values from it.

Comment: @Esskay In which environment are you using the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my tool uses JAVA flavour of regex

Comment: @Thefourthbird it's a log managment tool, which uses java flavour of regex.

Comment: Good, `(?:\G(?!\A),|Abstrac\w+:)([^\s,]+)` will work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its working in pcre but not in javascript.

Comment: Sure, but you said you were using *JAVA flavour of regex*. In JS, you will need to split the captured value with additional code. Unless it is ECMAScript 2018+ compliant. Then, `(?<=Abstrac\w+:\S*?)[^\s,]+` will work.